# difference in checkpoint of Tensorflow version 0.11 and version 0.12?

Tags: tensorflow

I developed a CNN algorithm using Python and Tensorflow library.
I run the program on two Tensorflow versions as 0.11 and 0.12.
In the generated checkpoint folder, there is a difference between two versions:

1. Version 0.11

   - checkpoint100.ckp
   - checkpoint100.ckp.meta
2. Version 0.12

   - checkpoint100.ckp.index
   - checkpoint100.ckp.meta
   - checkpoint100.ckp.data-00000-of-00001

So could anybody explain what is actual difference in checkpoint between 2 tensorflow versions? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TensorFlow 0.12, we introduced the more efficient "V2" checkpoint format, with two main differences:

- A V2 checkpoint includes a separate `.index` file, which provides  a compact index of the particular data file (and location within that file) where a particular saved tensor can be found.
- The V2 checkpoint format supports larger tensors than its predecessor (which used a Protocol Buffer to store tensor values, with a limit of at most 2GB per tensor).

The [`tf.train.Saver` initializer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver#__init__) accepts an optional `write_version` argument, which controls the format that is used when writing a checkpoint, and defaults to the V2 format. Since TensorFlow 0.12, the `tf.train.Saver` has supported reading and writing both checkpoint formats.